# Calculate pairwise cosine distance only returning the lower triangular matrix

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, computational-mathematics

I have a matrix, where each row is a feature vector. 
I would like to find out the pairwise cosine distance between all of these feature vectors.
The cosine value between all rows in a matrix could be calculated as

$\cos(M) = M' \cdot M'^T$

Where $M'$ is the row normalized matrix of $M$.
This creates a symmetric matrix of pairwise cosine distances, and it is pretty fast to calculate this using the sparse matrix library in scipy. I was wondering if there is an alternative method of only calculating the lower triangular matrix of this, rather than the full symmetric matrix? Hopefully this would be dividing the necessary computational time by two and saving a bit of space.

Thanks

Comment: This is really a programming question and is incorrectly tagged.

Comment: @Paul I thought about whether this was a programming or math question, but since it is more about the method of calculation than the implementation, I was thinking it was indeed more of a math question. Do you disagree?

Comment: it reads like you know how to do the calculation and that the problem is to extract some coefficients and not others. Is that not a computational issue? Maybe add some computation tags?

Comment: @Paul I updated the question to make it a bit more clear that I'm looking for an alternative cosine calculation that would only calculate the lower triangular matrix rather than the full symmetric matrix.

Comment: You might still add further tags though - this is really just about finding a computational advantage.

Answer (score 0):

`Y = pdist(X, 'cosine')` does that directly -- see
[scipy.spatial.distance.pdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) .
(`spatial.distance` seems to be missing in the doc for [scipy.spatial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html) in v0.16.0, so hard to find :/ )